# Cast SDK V3 : Modify Cast NotificationOptions runtime

Tags: java, android, chromecast

Is it possible to modify `NotificationOptions` runtime?

The application I am working on requires different actions based on these features:

- For Video : REWIND,TOGGLE_PLAYBACK,FORWARD
- For Audio : TOGGLE_PLAYBACK

Also, is it possible to trigger Notification when application is in Foreground?

Cast documentation mentioned ["The Notification will only be shown when the app is in the background."](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/MediaNotificationService)

I spent enough time going through CastSDK documentation but haven't found any solution. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Is it possible to modify `NotificationOptions` runtime?**

- I don't see a way to directly modify `NotificationOptions` runtime but it would help if you initialize the Cast Context. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#initialize_the_cast_context)

  > Your app must implement the `OptionsProvider` interface to supply options needed to initialize the CastContext singleton. OptionsProvider provides an instance of CastOptions which contains options that affect the behavior of the framework.

After initialization, you can then add expanded controller wherein you can declare your new activity then edit the `CastOptionsProvider` and change `NotificationOptions` and `CastMediaOptions` to set the target activity to your new activity:

```
 public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
        NotificationOptions notificationOptions = new NotificationOptions.Builder()
                .setTargetActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
                .build();
        CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
                .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
                .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
                .build();

        return new CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
            .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
            .build();
 }
```

Please go through the given documentation for other things that you can do after initializing the cast context such as configuring device discovery and also additional details on how session management works.

**2. Is it possible to trigger Notification when application is in Foreground?**

- [Notification and Lock Screen](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/android_migrate_sender#notification_and_lock_screen) in Cast SDK V3,

  > the SDK provides a `NotificationsOptions.Builder` to help you build media controls for the notification and lock screen into the sender app. The notification and lock screen controls can be enabled with the CastOptions when initializing the CastContext.

Furthermore, to add some clarity, it was stated in [Media Controls to Notification and Lock Screen](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#add_media_controls_to_notification_and_lock_screen) that

> `MediaNotificationService` runs in the background when the sender is casting but does not have focus, and will show a notification with image thumbnail and information about the current casting item, a play/pause button and a stop button.

**Warning:** If you're building a v3 app or migrating to v3, you should be using `CastContext` and not GoogleAPIClient for accessing the Cast API.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Teyam, I have implemented all the framework component exactly mentioned in documentation and everything is working fine.Only problem i am facing is to have different Notification actions based on features.If  i am right from you comments its look like we don't have any way to have modify

Comment: NotificationOptions after CastContext initialize.

Answer (score 0):

To have dynamic actions in cast notifications, use [NotificationActionsProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/NotificationActionsProvider). You can find a complete guide in the docs.